# Querying Mongo across Two Arrays

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have the following document structure:

```
{ _id : 1,
  items: [ {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, ..., {n: "Age", v: 100} ],
  records : [ {n: "Environment", v: "Linux"}, ... , {n: "RecordNumber, v: 555} ]
}
```

If I create 2 compound indexes on `items.n-items.v` and `records.n-records.v`, I could perform an `$all` query:

`db.collection.find( {"items" : {$all : [{ $elemMatch: {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"} },

{$elemMatch: {n: "Age", v: 100} } ]}})`

I could also perform a similar search on `records`.

`db.collection.find( {"records" : {$all : [{ $elemMatch: {n: "Environment", v: "Linux"} },

{$elemMatch: {n: "RecordNumber", v: 555} } ]}})`

Can I somehow perform a query that uses the index(es) to search for a document based on the **items** and **records** field?

> find all documents where item.n = "Name" and item.v = "Kevin" AND record.n="RecordNumber" and record.v = 100

I'm not sure that this is possible using `$all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an index to query on one array, but not both. Per the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations), `While you can create multikey compound indexes, at most one field in a compound index may hold an array`.

Practically:

- You can use a `Compound` index to index multiple fields.
- You can use a `Multikey` index to index all the elements of an array.
- You can use a `Multikey` index as one element of a `compound` Index
- You **CANNOT** use *multiple* `multikey` indexes in a `compound` index

The documentation lays out the reason for this pretty clearly:

> MongoDB does not index parallel arrays because they require the index to include each value in the Cartesian product of the compound keys, which could quickly result in incredibly large and difficult to maintain indexes.